# Netlify no me permite tener 2 pestañas de mi proyecto abiertas simultaneamente

Tags: sql, reactjs

Verán, tengo un proyecto en Netifly a nombre https://concesionario-daniel.netlify.app, en el cual tengo una página de un concesionario web.
Tengo una página de inicio.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Inicio = () => {
  return (
    <main className="Wrap">
      <h1>
        <u>¡Bienvenido a los Concesionarios Max!</u>
      </h1>
      <p>
        ¿Buscas un coche de última generación? ¿Uno barato? ¿Uno con mucho
        espacio?
        <br />
        Sea cual sea el coche que estes buscando, ¡Aquí lo encontrarás!
      </p>
      <Link to="/coche">
        <button className="VcButton">Lista de Coches</button>
      </Link>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Inicio;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta página de inicio tiene un botón que lleva la lista de coches. Si pulso el botón con el botón izquierdo del ratón, lo cual reemplaza la pestaña, funciona.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si decido pulsar el botón central, el cual crea una nueva pestaña en vez de reemplazar la actual:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale este mensaje de error. Es decir, solo puedo tener una pestaña de mi proyecto abierta al mismo tiempo.
¿A que se deberá este error?

Edito: He descubierto que también me da el error si intento dirigirme a la ruta escribiéndola en el teclado, sin importar si tengo abierta alguna pestaña del proyecto o no. Parece que Netlify solo permite moverse pulsando en el botón con el botón izquierdo.

Edito: Esta es la lista de rutas de la página, que están en la carpeta client->src->components->App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

import Header from './Header.js';
import Footer from './Footer.js';

import Inicio from '../pages/Inicio.js';
import ListaCoche from '../pages/ListaCoche.js';
import ListaCliente from '../pages/ListaCliente.js';
import ListaEmpleado from '../pages/ListaEmpleado.js';
import ListaTienda from '../pages/ListaTienda.js';
import ListaCompra from '../pages/ListaCompra.js';
import CrearCoche from '../pages/CrearCoche.js';
import CrearCliente from '../pages/CrearCliente.js';
import CrearEmpleado from '../pages/CrearEmpleado.js';
import CrearTienda from '../pages/CrearTienda.js';
import CrearCompra from '../pages/CrearCompra.js';
import ModificarCoche from '../pages/ModificarCoche.js';
import ModificarCliente from '../pages/ModificarCliente.js';
import ModificarEmpleado from '../pages/ModificarEmpleado.js';
import ModificarTienda from '../pages/ModificarTienda.js';
import ModificarCompra from '../pages/ModificarCompra.js';
import ErrorPage from '../pages/Error.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Inicio} />
          <Route path="/coche" component={ListaCoche} />
          <Route path="/cliente" component={ListaCliente} />
          <Route path="/empleado" component={ListaEmpleado} />
          <Route path="/tienda" component={ListaTienda} />
          <Route path="/compra" component={ListaCompra} />
          <Route path="/crearcoche" component={CrearCoche} />
          <Route path="/crearcliente" component={CrearCliente} />
          <Route path="/creartienda" component={CrearTienda} />
          <Route path="/crearempleado" component={CrearEmpleado} />
          <Route path="/crearcompra" component={CrearCompra} />
          <Route path="/modificarcoche/:id" component={ModificarCoche} />
          <Route path="/modificarcliente/:id" component={ModificarCliente} />
          <Route path="/modificarempleado/:id" component={ModificarEmpleado} />
          <Route path="/modificartienda/:id" component={ModificarTienda} />
          <Route path="/modificarcompra/:id" component={ModificarCompra} />
          <Route path="/*" component={ErrorPage} />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Queria escribir una respuesta pero..., la respuesta es que no tienes las url`s en tu servidor.

Comment: @Shassain ¿Poner las URL en el servidor? ¿Te refieres a las rutas de la carpeta client?

Comment: @Shassain He editado para colocar más datos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que al hacer click en algun botón del encabezado solo cambia el url
de la página (y no pasa a otra pagina) porque React maneja la apariencia de la página
con JavaScript. Si luego, intentas abrir la url cambiada en otra pestaña, Netlify,
intenta buscar un archivo "/coches", "/clientes", etc y no lo encuentra porque es
una [Single Page Application](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) y el codigo de la página está en "/index.html" (o "/"
que carga el mismo archivo).

Una solución es usar un Rewrite (reescritura) de la url que provee Netlify, que
hace que al usar una url de las secciones, no trate de cargar un archivo inexistente
sino el archivo principal de la aplicación.

Hay [dos formas](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects) de hacer el Rewrite, una es crear un archivo llamado
"_redirects" en el [directorio de publicación](https://docs.netlify.com/configure-builds/get-started/#basic-build-settings) (publish directory) con
el siguiente contenido:

`_redirects`

```plaintext
/*    /index.html    200
```

La primera columna es el patrón que debe seguir la ruta a reescribir, la
segunda es el objetivo y la tercera indica que va a reescribir la url y no
[redireccionarla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302).

La otra forma es editar el archivo de configuración "netlify.toml" en el
directorio del codigo fuente y agregar lo siguiente:

`netlify.toml`

```toml
[[redirects]]
  from = "/*"
  to = "/index.html"
  status = 200
  force = true # si el archivo en `from` existe lo ignora
```